# PyQt5 QGraphicsView transparent background

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I use PyQt5 and python 3.6

I use the QtWidgets.QGraphicsView only to determine mouse position data and I want to paint in the background.

How can I set the QtWidgets.QGraphicsView transparent?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

  class Ui_Controller(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, setting):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 150, 1610, 1207)
        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
        self.graphicsView.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphicsView)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        #paint something 

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
                pos = event.pos()
                print(str(pos.x())+' '+ str(pos.y()))
            else:
                pass # do other stuff
        return QtGui.QWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)
```

this is only a example class.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `setStyleSheet("background: transparent")` or whatever the equivalent is for PyQt?

Comment: I checked it and it is there. It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried that out!

```
self.graphicsView.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;")
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to specify the backgroud color and not the background.
So:

```py
self.graphicsView.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;")
```

I use Qt 5.14.1 on C++